# Will an instance be garbage collected if a thread which was created by it is still running?

Tags: c#, multithreading, reference, garbage-collection, task

```
public class ServiceA
{
    public ServiceA()
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            while (true) { }
        });
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public void Main()
    {
        new ServiceA(); // new ServiceA without any variable referencing to it

        //...
        //...
        //...
        //...
        //...
        //...
        //...
        //...
        //...
        //...
        //...

        Console.WriteLine("Would 'new ServiceA()' still alive and won't be GC"
            + " since its task is still running?");
    }
}
```

Please consider above code. I wonder if `ServiceA`'s instance will be GC as it always "born" a Task which will never end. However, I did not make any reference to the `Task` at all. (i.e. `this.task1 = Task.Run(/.../)`). Does it mean that the Task will still alive even `ServiceA` instance will be GC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The task it spawned has ZERO relationship to ServiceA, so it will obviously not stop ServiceA from being collected. What counts is not some arcane once upon a time relationship, but only relationships that the garbage collector can see at the time it is executing. If the thread has a variable that holds a reference to the instance of ServiceA it is safe from collection, but such a collection is not in your code.

Comment: I don't know C#, but in a certain other language, I would expect that the task object created by the lambda expression might contain an implicit reference to the instance whose `ServiceA()` method created it.

Comment: @SolomonSlow it seems you are talking about that certain other language that has such an issue with inner classes. Since this code example has no inner classes but only a lambda expression, even with that certain other language nothing not prevents the collection of the `ServiceA` instance. In fact, not even the task object is prevented from garbage collection. Only the object representing the native thread resource will stay in memory for sure.

Comment: @Holger, In other words, you are saying that because the lambda expression does not refer to any member of the class in which it appears, then it is _guaranteed_ not to capture `this`. OK, Sure. I'm not going to verify that at this time, but I _will_ go go look for that guarantee, _in writing_, before I write any code that depends on it to be true.

Comment: @SolomonSlow for Java, you won’t find it in the specification, but the specification is silent about the other behavior, i.e. that inner classes always capture `this`, either. The question is, which behavior is actually needing a guaranty, that the object is prevented from garbage collection (i.e. its finalizer won’t run when there is one) or that the garbage collection is possible (which still wouldn’t guaranty that it actually happens and even if it does, still doesn’t guaranty that its finalizer will run).